# Faster/Piped version of Stream.CopyTo

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I was shocked to see that the default implementation of Stream.CopyTo is not piped. No piping means that no reading on the source is done whilst writing to the destination.

This means that in most cases performance is half of what it could be. (Copy Filestream from C: to another HDD)

How do I implement a fast piped CopyTo?

Answer (score 1):

Files have sequential read-ahead and write buffering directly from the operating system. You are unlikely to improve performance of the most basic `Copy` implementation in those cases.

TCP sockets similarly will buffer quite a bit of data for you, and so the basic `Copy` should be fine for them too so long as your protocol allows for bulk data sends.

When you open the file up as unbuffered (very rare -- typically you do this if you can perform your own caching that you know will be better than the OS), or have a poorly designed network protocol is where performing your own special buffering might give sizable improvements.

Something like this should be sufficient in most of those cases...

```
static async Task CopyMaybeFaster(Stream src, Stream dst)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
    int curoff = 0;

    Task<int> readTask = src.ReadAsync(buffer, curoff, 32768);
    Task writeTask = Task.CompletedTask;
    int len;

    while ((len = await readTask.ConfigureAwait(false)) != 0)
    {
        await writeTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
        writeTask = dst.WriteAsync(buffer, curoff, len);

        curoff ^= 32768;
        readTask = src.ReadAsync(buffer, curoff, 32768);
    }

    await writeTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: This code is not piped. All you do here is await on the read and the await on the write. The control goes back to the caller and it does not Read and WRITE at the same time. This is not faster at all.

Comment: No. Defining a task does not execute it. You only await a single task at any time. Your code would be Piped if you would Task.WaitAll on both tasks.

Comment: Your understanding of tasks is flawed. `ReadAsync` and `WriteAsync` return *hot* tasks -- ones that are already started. `await` merely waits for a task to finish, it does not start/run the task.

Comment: Isn't this code similar to what the CopyToAsync method does ?

Comment: Shouldn't the WriteAsync operation be done on the dst stream ? And why do you read/write only half of the buffer size ?

Comment: @FrederikGheysels there are two ops going at once, each op uses one half of the buffer. Also thanks for noticing `WriteAsync` pointing to the wrong stream -- fixed.

Answer (score -2):

This is the most robust implementation I could think of:

```
public void CopyTo_Fast(Stream Destination, int Buffersize)
{
    byte[] BufferA = new byte[Buffersize];
    byte[] BufferB = new byte[Buffersize];
    int Abytes = Read(BufferA, 0, BufferA.Length);//read first buffer
    if (Abytes < Buffersize) //trivial case stream too small for two buffers
    {
        Destination.Write(BufferA, 0, Abytes);
        return;
    }
    int Bbytes = 0;
    Task Writer;
    Task Reader;

    while(true) //Read to end
    {
        Writer = Task.Run(() => Destination.Write(BufferA, 0, Abytes));
        Reader = Task.Run(() => Bbytes = Read(BufferB, 0, Buffersize));
        Task.WaitAll(Writer, Reader);
        if (Bbytes == 0) return;

        Writer = Task.Run(() => Destination.Write(BufferB, 0, Bbytes));
        Reader = Task.Run(() => Abytes = Read(BufferA, 0, Buffersize));
        Task.WaitAll(Writer, Reader);
        if (Abytes == 0) return;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very bad suggestion - asynchronous wrappers over synchronous code is not a good practice (especially when true async option is present), waiting on tasks is likely to cause deadlocks. Additionally OP made unsubstantiated claim that .net version is slow,but this answer does not cover performance part at all.

Comment: Well to have a synchronous piped version multithreading is needed. All examples used the old BeginRead and EndRead syntax. This is much easier to maintain. I will add the performance difference and the async version. This code also has no deadlocks.